# Saving a binary file in custom location in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

My Cocoa app saves data to a random location ( say /tmp) and once the user is done editing this file and say, hits " Done Editing", I want to prompt the user to save a file in a location of his choice.
Any pointers on how to accomplish this in Cocoa ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `NSSavePanel`, like so:

```
- (IBAction)doneEditingAction:(NSButton *)sender
{
    NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    NSWindow *documentWindow = [[self document] window];
    [panel
     beginSheetModalForWindow:documentWindow
     completionHandler:^(NSInteger button) {
         switch (button) {
         case NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton: {
             NSString *saveURL = [panel URL];
             [self saveFileToPath:saveURL];
             break;
         }
         default:  /* FALL THROUGH */
         case NSFileHandlingPanelCancelButton:
             break;
         }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [NSOpenPanel](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html).